# -bash: /usr/local/share/etc/bashrc: Connection timed out when coonecting to linux server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

When connecting to the server, it shows,

```
-bash: /usr/local/share/etc/bashrc: Connection timed out
```

What extra information should I provide to help troubleshooting this?

After running  mount|cut -f1-3 -d' '
It returns:

```
sysfs on /sys
proc on /proc
devtmpfs on /dev
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs on /dev/shm
devpts on /dev/pts
tmpfs on /run
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
configfs on /sys/kernel/config
/dev/mapper/vg_cen7-lv_root on /
/dev/mapper/vg_cen7-lv_usr on /usr
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
mqueue on /dev/mqueue
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
/dev/sda2 on /boot
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1 on /u
/dev/mapper/vg_cen7-lv_tmp on /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg_cen7-lv_var on /var
/dev/mapper/vg_cen7-lv_opt on /opt
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
AFS on /afs
tmpfs on /run/user/3312
```

Best
Max

Comment: `mount|cut -f1-3 -d' '` to confirm that /usr/local is an nfs mount.  This is not really a bash question.

Comment: @AllanWind Hi, Allan. Thank you for the suggestion. I just run the comment you suggested, and I edited the post with the return. What should I do next?

Comment: Hmm.... not what what I expected as `/dev/mapper/vg_cen7-lv_usr on /usr` appears to be the the partition, but if /usr is off-line then you are probably logging in.  Maybe it's a symlink to something on AFS?  Try `ls -dl /usr/local /usr/local/share /usr/local/local/share/etc /usr/local/share/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: @AllanWind I get this, `ls: cannot access /usr/local/share: Connection timed out` `ls: cannot access /usr/local/local/share/etc: Connection timed out` `ls: cannot access /usr/local/share/etc/bashrc: Connection timed out` and `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 44 Oct 12  2021 /usr/local -> /afs/cs.university.edu/system/amd64_cen7/usr/local
`

Comment: Perfect.  This means that /usr/local ls a symlink to /afs/cs.university.edu/system/amd64_cen7/usr/local.  The andrew file system (AFS) is a networked file system, and it appears to be off-line.  I don't know anything about AFS, I am afraid, but now you can ask the right question probably on server fault instead of stack overflow.